# How can I send a daily task reminder email?

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, designer-workflow

My teammates and I (4 of us total) use a task log in SharePoint to keep track of tasks.  I have been tasked (hah!) with creating a daily summary email to be sent to each user containing tasks overdue, tasks due today, and tasks coming due (within the next 5 days, let's say).

This email should go out daily, the time is flexibly (probably before 9 am).

I can't do timer jobs as I don't have Visual Studio nor do I have SharePoint Server installed on my machine.

I would like to do this via a workflow, if possible.  It can pause for 24 hours, etc. if need be, but I have no clue how to get started.  I've been googling for 4 days now and am not much better off for it.

The basic summary email should look like this:

```
Hello [User],

You have [X] tasks past due:
 - [Task 1]
 - [Task 2]

You have [Y] tasks due today:
 - [Task 1]

You have [Z] tasks due within 5 days:
 - [Task 1]
 - [Task 2]
 - [Task 3]
```

SharePoint version is 2010, I have SPD 2013 installed on my machine.  I do not have SharePoint Server.

Comment: What is your SharePoint version? 2013/online, 2010 or 2007?

Comment: Sharepoint is 2010, I have SPD 2013 on my machine

Answer (score 1):

Loop conditions are not available in Sharepoint 2010 workflow. It is available only in 2013. If you have a 2013 based workflow, then you can pause until 24 hours and loop it, so that it runs everyday.